POST запрос в PHP из OkHttp
Код в приложении Андроид
 RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("Message", "Hello")
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://example.com/test.php")
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Call call = client.newCall(request);

            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = call.execute();
                String serverResponse = response.body().string();
                // Do something with the response

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

код в принимающем  PHP
<?php
 $Message=$_POST['Message'];
echo $Message;
?>

Библиотека OkHttp v 4.12.0.
После выполнения кода в test.php ничего не приходит. Приложение вылетает. Помогите разобраться

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

нужно получить данные из Андроид приложения в php обработчик

Вы уверены, что идет POST запрос, а не GET? Ваш test.php вообще вызывается?

да. test.php вызывается из сети через http://example.com/test.php в браузере. в манифесте доступ в интернет предоставлен. В пользу POST запроса говорит это '.post(formBody)'

А как вы узнали, что "ничего не приходит"? РНР выдаёт ошибку?

Когда я обновляю в браузере страницу, ожидаю выполнения вывода из echo $Message, а его нет. Правильно ли я проверяю?

Do something with the response -- очень правильное замечание. Что там в ответе?

Попробовал вывести в setText . Приложение сразу закрывается

Когда вы "обновляете в браузере страницу" массив $_POST по определению будет пустой. Что вы собираетесь при этом увидеть? Вы понимаете, что браузер - это не ваше приложение андроид, и никакую форму вы при обновлении страницы в браузере не посылаете?

разве $Message в test.php не заполняется методом POST? Как мне увидеть содержимое  $Message?

Дополняю - приложение вылетает

Что бы отправлять и получать результат методом POST обычно пользуются программами по типу POSTMAN
